# Are there immutable direct access URLs to DocuSign Home or Management page?

Tags: docusignapi

### Context

My team is working on an integration between a **Web Application** and **DocuSign**, where the user may send files to signing from our App to DocuSign (creating an envelope with the files).

In the envelope info inside our app, the user should have a **link to be redirected to DocuSign** (preferably to the Management page, but Home one is also acceptable).

### Question

Since there isn't an endpoint on [DocuSign eSignature API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference) for getting a redirect URL (such as [EnvelopeViews](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/)), and I couldn't find a document mentioning *direct access* to DocuSign eSignature (such as the one existing for [DocuSign eSignature Admin](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-access)), my question is...

**Is there a known redirect URL to DocuSign eSignature that I could trust it won't change**, so I can use it on our application?

I found out (looking at the authentication process) that the following URLs work for what I want...

- https://appdemo.docusign.com/authentication?back=/home (Sandbox)
- https://app.docusign.com/authentication?back=/home (Prod)
- https://appdemo.docusign.com/authentication?back=/documents (Sandbox)
- https://app.docusign.com/authentication?back=/documents (Prod)

**But can I trust they won't change (since they aren't documented) and use them on my app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the management/web app for users, there's a way to do that with the API, you get back a URL that is pre-authenticated and is the recommended way to do that.
See here for [code examples](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedding-console) in different languages.
As for the administration/settings part, you would have to do it the way you indicated. We cannot guarantee this URL would never change, but it's not something that happen often if at all. However, users would have to log in (authenticate) when they are redirected unless in the same browser and already logged in.

Comment: Thank you very much @Inbar! Although I had seen the [EnvelopeViews:createConsole](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createConsole) before, I didn't realize so far **it is exactly what I'm looking for** (at least for the home page). And it's also good to know those URLs I mentioned usually don't change, although they may.